# jquery image width() is not returning correct value in IE9

Tags: jquery

We have an image tag with width and height specified as auto so that we can get the width and height of the actual image. So we use the following to get them.

```
$("img.list-image").width()
$("img.list-image").height()
```

in FF, Chrome, IE8 and safari, the width and height returned are 125 pixel and 160 pixel respectively and these values are correct. But in IE9, the width is 1519 pixels and the height is 771 pixels. For some reason, these width and height functions are not returning proper values in IE9. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Following is the code We are using

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Image Page</title>
    <style type="text/css" >
    .list-category-image
    {
        border-width: 0px;display:none;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        $(function() {
            categoryImageaspectratio();
        });

        function categoryImageaspectratio() {
            $("img.list-category-image").one('load', function() {
                var width = 85.0, height = 85.0;
                var realWidth, realHeight;
                realWidth = $(this).width();   // Note: $(this).width() will not
                realHeight = $(this).height();

                //alert("width, height = (" + realWidth + "," + realHeight + ")");

                // Now scale the image.
                var aspectRatio = 1.0;
                if (realHeight / height > realWidth / width) {
                    aspectRatio = realHeight / height;
                    width = realWidth / aspectRatio;
                }
                else {
                    aspectRatio = realWidth / width;
                    height = realHeight / aspectRatio;
                    //alert("aspectRatio = " + aspectRatio);
                    //alert("height = " + height);
                }

                var imgWidth = parseInt(width) + "px";
                var imgHeight = parseInt(height) + "px";

                //alert(imgWidth + ", " + imgHeight);

                //   $(this).css("width", imgWidth).css("heigth", imgHeight).css('display', 'block');
                $(this).css("width", imgWidth).css("heigth", imgHeight).css('display', 'block').css('text-align', 'center').css('margin-left', 'auto').css('margin-right', 'auto');
            }).each(function() {
                if (this.complete) {
                        $(this).load();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:85px; height:85px;">
        <img class="list-category-image" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/411j0fCdVKL._SL160_.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a (non-)working demo?

Comment: Are you using the latest stable version of jQuery? Older versions may not support IE9.

Comment: I have added the code to reproduce the issue

Comment: @mohang nobody of the above three people saw your comment or edit - you need to notify each using `@` to send them notifications.

Comment: Getting `125,160` with IE9 in this test page: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ba98/

Comment: I was using jQuery 1.4.2 version. Now I changed to jQuery 1.5.1 and the issue got fixed. Thanks  Luc1245.

Answer (score 1):

using this keyword is always very tricky and sometimes confusing, it can be different values in different implementations of javascript. try to define your image as a variable to see if it fixes your problem:

```
       var imgList = $("img.list-category-image");
       imgList.one('load', function() {

            var width = 85.0, height = 85.0;
            var realWidth, realHeight;
            realWidth = imgList.width();   // Note: $(this).width() will not
            realHeight = imgList.height();
```

you can use the following code to check what the type of this is:

```
alert(typeof(this));
```

Comment: But we had several images for which we needed, so perhaps a loop is required to get this working. However we solved the situation by adding the jQuery 1.5.1 version which fixed the issue. Thanks for trying. and +1 for your effort.